# Split according to regex condition

Tags: python, regex

This will be my another question:

```
string = "Organization: S.P. Dyer Computer Consulting, Cambridge MA"
```

How can I take all the characters despite it being fullstop, digits, or anything after "Organization: " using regex?

```
result_organization = re.search("(Organization: )(\w*\.*\w*\.*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*)", string)
```

My above code is super long and not wise at all.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `Organization: (.*)` https://regex101.com/r/mMNpOm/1

Comment: Why not just `.*`?

Comment: Can u please explain a little about .* ??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for that, this simple code should give you desired result:

```
str = "Organization: S.P. Dyer Computer Consulting, Cambridge MA";
if str.startswith("Organization: "):
    str = str[14:];

print(str)
```

You also could use pattern `(?<=Organization: ).+`

Explanation:

`(?<=Organization: )` - positive lookbehind, asserts if what is preceeding is `Organization:`

`.+` - match any character except for newline characters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yVHIhv/1)

Comment: Thank you sir for the help.

Comment: I am sorry sir, but it seems like there will be an issue when we have a string like this string = "Organization: S.P. Dyer Computer Consulting, Cambridge MA\n\nTechnical term need to add in." However, I just want to get until Cambridge MA.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using find command like this

```
 print(string[string.find("Organization")+14:])
```

Comment: I am sorry sir, but it seems like there will be an issue when we have a string like this string = "Organization: S.P. Dyer Computer Consulting, Cambridge MA\n\nTechnical term need to add in." However, I just want to get until Cambridge MA.

Comment: Can you assist in regex if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single capturing group instead of 2 capturing groups.

Instead of specify all the words `(\w*\.*\w*\.*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*)` you might choose to match any character except a newline using the dot and then match the 0+ times to match until the end.

But note that that would also match strings like `#@$$ ++`

```
^Organization: (.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RfT3FO/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PB0Eog)

For example

```
import re
string = "Organization: S.P. Dyer Computer Consulting, Cambridge MA"
result_organization = re.search("Organization: (.*)", string)
print(result_organization.group(1))
```

If you want a somewhat more restrictive pattern you might use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and specify what you would allow to match. For example:

```
^Organization: ([\w.,]+(?: [\w.,]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RfT3FO/2)